# spring-boot TCP server: wait for `empty line` before answering a `multi-line` request

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, sockets, tcp

I would like to write a custom `check_policy_service` (http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) for postfix with spring-boot.

Short: postfix sends multiple lines like:

```
foo=bar
me=you
year=123
[empty line]
```

The empty line indicates, that the request is complete, now the spring-boot app should handle the data and return something like `action=ok`

Problem:
In my current setup the app tries to handle line 1 `foo=bar` immediately and does not wait until the `[empty line]` is sent. How can I make the app wait for the empty line?

Current setup:
spring-boot 2.6.3

```kotlin
@Configuration
class TcpServerConfig {
//    @Value("\${tcp.server.port}")
    private val port = 6676
    @Bean
    fun serverConnectionFactory(): AbstractServerConnectionFactory {
        val serverConnectionFactory = TcpNioServerConnectionFactory(port)
        serverConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true)
        serverConnectionFactory.isSingleUse = false // reuse socket
        return serverConnectionFactory
    }
    @Bean
    fun inboundChannel(): MessageChannel {
        return DirectChannel()
    }

    @Bean
    fun inboundGateway(
        serverConnectionFactory: AbstractServerConnectionFactory,
        inboundChannel: MessageChannel
    ): TcpInboundGateway {
        val tcpInboundGateway = TcpInboundGateway()
        tcpInboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory)
        tcpInboundGateway.setRequestChannel(inboundChannel)
        return tcpInboundGateway
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@MessageEndpoint
class TcpServerEndpoint {

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inboundChannel")
    fun process(message: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        
        // I would need to have `message` contain every line until empty line - not a single line        
        println(String(message))
        
        // TODO handle message accordingly
        return "action=ok\n".toByteArray()
    }
}
```

I am not sure where to hook in. Maybe `DirectChannel` needs to be something else?

I wrote a quick non spring-boot implementation which works, so basically I need the spring-boot-ified version of:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val server = ServerSocket(9999)
    println("Server is running on port ${server.localPort}")

    while (true) {
        val client = server.accept()
        println("Client connected: ${client.inetAddress.hostAddress}")

        // Run client in it's own thread.
        thread { ClientHandler(client).run() }
    }

}

class ClientHandler(client: Socket) {
    private val client: Socket = client
    private val reader: BufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
    private val writer: PrintWriter = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    private var running: Boolean = false

    fun run() {
        running = true
        while (running) {
            try {
                do {
                    val line = reader.readLine() ?: break
                    // TODO collect all lines in a list and handle
                } while (line.isNotEmpty())

                write("action=ok")

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                // TODO: Implement exception handling
                ex.printStackTrace()
                shutdown()
            } finally {

            }
        }
    }

    private fun write(message: String) {
        writer.write((message + "\n\n"))
        writer.flush()
    }
    private fun shutdown() {
        running = false
        client.close()
        println("${client.inetAddress.hostAddress} closed the connection")
    }
}
```

The magic part is read all lines until line is empty and then handle the request(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Deserializer` so that Spring knows when to release the read content (so far) to the handler as described in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs).

In your case, you should write a custom deserializer implementing the interface `org.springframework.core.serializer.Deserializer` that releases the content to the handler as soon as it has detected two newlines in a row. Make it return a `List<String>` with the lines sent by Postfix:

```
class DoubleNewLineDeserializer: Deserializer<List<String>> {

    companion object {
        const val UNIX_NEWLINE = "\n\n"
        const val WINDOWS_NEWLINE = "\r\n\r\n"
        val CRLFRegex = Regex("[\r\n]+")
    }

    override fun deserialize(inputStream: InputStream): List<String> {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        while(!builder.endsWith(UNIX_NEWLINE) && !builder.endsWith(WINDOWS_NEWLINE))
            builder.append(inputStream.read().toChar())
        return builder.toString().split(CRLFRegex).filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
    }

}
```

This deserializer reads input until it finds a double new line (here either `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n`, you can modify this as you want) at which point it removes the message delimiter and then returns the message as a list of lines.

Finally, set your new deserializer on the `ServerConnectionFactory`:

```
serverConnectionFactory.deserializer = DoubleNewLineDeserializer()
```

Input to TCP socket:

```
foo=bar
me=you
year=123
[empty line]
[empty line]
```

Input to handler:

```
[foo=bar, me=you, year=123]
```